# Why speed of variable length pipeline is determined by the slowest stage + whats the total execution time of program?

Tags: cpu-architecture

I am new to pipelining and I need some help regarding the fact that

> **The speed of the pipelining is determined by the speed of the slowest stage**

Not only this, if I am given a 5 stage pipeline with duration of them 5 ns,10 ns, 8 ns, 7 ns,7 ns respectively , it is said that each instruction would take 10 ns time.
Can I get a clear explanation for this?

**(edited**)
Also let my program has 3 instructions I1,I2,I3 and I take 1 clk cycle duration = 1ns 
such that the above stages take - 5, 10, 8 , 7 , 7 clock cycles respectively.
Now according to theory a snapshot of the pipeline would be -

[image: Simple Pipeline snapshot]

But that gives me a total time to be -no of clk cycles*clk cycle duration = 62 * 1 = 62 ns
But according to theory total time should be - (slowest stage) * no. of instructions = 10 * 3 = 30 ns
Though I have an idea why slowest stage is important (each pipeline stage needs to wait hence 1 instruction is produced after every 10 clk cycle- but the result is inconsistent when i calculate it using clk cycles.Why this inconsistency? What am I missing??
**(edited)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your answers

I think I have got it clear by now.
This is what I think the answer is -

**Question- 1  :-  Why pipeline execution dependent on the slowest step**

Well clearly from the diagram each stage has to wait for the slowest stage to complete.
So the total time after which each instruction is completed bounded by the time of wait.
(In my example after a gap of 10 ns)

**Question-2  :- Whats the total execution time of program**

I wanted to know how long will the particular program containing 3 instructions take to execute
**NOT how long will it take for 3 instructions to execute**- which is obviously 30ns pertaining to the fact 
that every instruction gets completed every 10 ns.

Now suppose I1 is fetched in the pipeline then already 4 other instructions are executing in it.
4 instructions are completed in 40 ns time.
After that I1,I2,I3 executed in order  30 ns.(Assuming no pipeline stalls)

This gives a total of 30+40=70ns .

In fact for n instruction program,k- stage pipeline

I think it is **(n + k-1 ) *C *T**

where C= no. of clk cycles in slowest stage
 T= clock cycle time

Please review my understanding .... to know if I am thinking anything wrong and so that 
 I can accept my own answer!!!

Comment: You have a set up time that you are counting. This happens because your last instructions goes through the pipeline alone.

Comment: @maverick1989 - I was counting the duration between the time when I1 was first fetched and the time when I3 finished execution. 
What do you mean by last instructions goes alone through pipeline? Should the previous 4 instructions that adds 40 ns be not counted?? Please clarify.

Comment: Yes my point exactly. How much time does I3 take to go through the pipeline? Please trace the location of the other two instructions in the pipeline when I3 is at each stage.

Answer (score 3):

Assume a car manufacturing process. Assume it's used two stage pipe lining. Say it takes 1 day to manufacture an engine. 2 days to manufacture the rest. You can do both stages in parallel. What is your car output rate? It should be one car per 2 days. Although you manufacture the rest in 1 day, you have to wait another day to get the engine.

In your case, although other stages finish their job in lesser time, you have to wait 10ns to get the whole process done

Comment: thanks for your answer. Can you please explain the edited question above??

Comment: Your pipeline has not been fully utilized. You can execute 5 instructions parallely. But here you are executing only 3 instructions parallel. If I further explains, it will take (5+10+8+7+7)=37ns to execute a single instruction. But when it is in a five stage pipeline, it will complete an instruction every 10ns(look at my car manufacturing example) That means 3 instructions can be completed in 30ns.

Comment: -So you mean I should view the pipeline as always fully utilized and spewing(completing) a instruction after every 10 ns.
So the program execution time should not be counted by no. of clock cycles from start but rather = spew rate * no. of instructions ???

Answer (score 1):

Staging allows you to do the "parts" of the same operation at onces.

I'll create a smaller example here, dropping the last 2 stages of your example: 5, 10, 8 ns

Let's take two operations:

```
5  10  8
   5   10  8 

| The first operation starts here
   | At stage 2 the second operation can start it's fist stage
   | However, since the stages take different amount of times,
   | the longest ones determines the runtime
       | the thirds stage can only start after the 2nd has completed: after 15ns
       | this is also true for the 2nd stage of the 2nd operation
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please explain to me the edited question??

Comment: AFAIK the speed is determined by the slowest stage, but not exactly `n*slowestExecutionTime`. However, if your `n` is high enough the difference becomes negligible. Take your example in the edited question and do this for I1 to I1000000000 ;D

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the source of your confusion. If one unit of your pipeline is taking longer, the units behind it cannot push the pipeline to move ahead until that unit is finished, even though they themselves are finished with their work. Like DPG said, try to look at it from the car manufacture line example. It is one of the most common ones given to explain a pipeline. If the units AHEAD of the slowest unit after finished quicker, it still doesn't matter because they have to wait until the slower unit finishes its work. So yes, your pipeline is executing 3 instructions for a total execution time of 30ns.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I got the idea why the slowest stage is important ...clear from the diagram. But for the next question, I wanted to know how long would my program containing I1, I2,I3 will execute ...and not how long will 3 instructions execute- which is obviously 30 ns !!!